# 自作APIをAxios.getで叩きたい

Tags: javascript, api, axios

APIを作成しました。
Postmanで目的のjsonデータを取得することができます。
フロントエンドでAxiosを用いると取得できません。
しばらく調べましたが、原因がわからなかったの教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

*`Postman`*
GET `http://localhost:4000/api/money/month`

```
{
  "date": "2022-09-11",
  "userId": 1
}
```

*`結果`*

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "userId": 1,
        "amount": 1200,
        "memo": "食費",
        "bool": true,
        "date": "2022-09-11T00:00:00.000Z",
        "createdAt": "2022-09-19T17:31:42.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-09-19T17:31:42.000Z",
        "UserId": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "userId": 1,
        "amount": 1200,
        "memo": "食費",
        "bool": true,
        "date": "2022-09-11T00:00:00.000Z",
        "createdAt": "2022-09-19T17:31:50.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-09-19T17:31:50.000Z",
        "UserId": 1
    },
]
```

*`バックエンドAPI`*

```
// 月単位でレコードを取得
router.get("/month", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const data = await Money.findAll({
      where: {
        date: { [Op.substring]: req.body.date.slice(0, 7) },
        userId: req.body.userId,
      },
    });
    if (!data) {
      return res.status(200).json({ msg: "該当データが存在しませんでした" });
    } else {
      return res.status(200).json(data);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

*`フロントエンド・コード`*

```
const { default: axios } = require("axios");

const data = {
  date: "2022-09-11",
  userId: 1,
};

const getFetch = async () => {
  const all = await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/api/money/month", data);
  console.log(all.data);
};

getFetch();
```

*`結果`*

```
node:internal/process/promises:279
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

解決しました。
Axiosは第2引数にbody要素ではなくparamsを渡すのですね。
ここが間違えていました。